# Mysql query reduce load time

Tags: mysql, performance, time, load

I use PHP Mysql.Here is my query,its load time about 3-4 minutes.How can i load it below 1 minute.

```
SELECT buyer.Buyer, ordr.ordr, ordr.Ship_Date, colour.Colour,
       sewing_effi.OP, sewing_effi.HEL, sewing_effi.Target, sewing_effi.TWH,
                    SUM(v_ci_input.qc_pass) AS Input,
                    SUM(sewing_input_daily.qc_pass) AS DInput,
                    SUM(sewing_output.Recieved) AS Recv,
                    SUM(sewing_output.QC_Pass) AS Toutput,
                    SUM(sewing_output_daily.QC_Pass) AS Doutput,
                    floor_line.Line,
                    floor_line.floor
            FROM  v_ci_input
            LEFT JOIN buyer
                ON  v_ci_input.Buyer=buyer.CBuyer   
            LEFT JOIN ordr
                ON  v_ci_input.Buyer=ordr.CBuyer AND
                    v_ci_input.Ordr=ordr.COrdr
            INNER JOIN colour
                ON  v_ci_input.Buyer=colour.CBuyer AND
                    v_ci_input.Ordr=colour.COrdr AND
                    v_ci_input.Colour=colour.CColour
            LEFT JOIN sewing_input_daily
                ON  v_ci_input.Barcode=sewing_input_daily.Barcode
            LEFT JOIN sewing_output_daily
                ON  v_ci_input.Barcode =sewing_output_daily.Barcode
            LEFT JOIN sewing_output
                ON  v_ci_input.Barcode = sewing_output.Barcode
            RIGHT JOIN floor_line
                ON  floor_line.Line=    v_ci_input.Line
            JOIN sewing_effi
                ON  floor_line.Line=sewing_effi.Line
            WHERE Ship_Status=0 AND floor_line.Line in('301')
              AND sewing_effi.DT=CURDATE()
            GROUP BY floor_line.Line,
                     v_ci_input.Buyer,
                     v_ci_input.Ordr,
                     v_ci_input.Colour
            ORDER BY floor_line.Line ASC"
```

Comment: Is `v_ci_input` a `VIEW`?

Comment: What table is `Ship_Status` in?  (It makes a _big_ difference.)

Comment: I cringe at the combination of `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `INNER`.  I don't know what is what.  Do you?  For, what is "left" of the `RIGHT JOIN`?  Just `sewing_output`?  Or everything before it?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  I am having trouble fathoming `Color`, `CColor`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First rule: check that you have working and useful indexes on columns that you are joining. This is the most common mistake and usually the biggest performance penalty. Rewrite your query to use `LEFT JOIN`s only and try to avoid `OUTER JOIN`s if possible.

Without detailed description, it is impossible to give any good advice. Do you know what execution plans are being used? What is the size and distribution statistics of data? What does each column actually mean and what do you want to do with the query? How much RAM do you have, what are your CPUs and disks? Database optimization is a large and complex topics...